# werkzeug hello world not doing anything

Tags: python, web-services, werkzeug

Currently have a hello world werkzeug web service, ran pip installs of everything I needed.  I run `python shortly.py` and it does nothing.

```
import os
import redis
import urlparse
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from werkzeug.routing import Map, Rule
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException, NotFound
from werkzeug.wsgi import SharedDataMiddleware
from werkzeug.utils import redirect
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader


class Shortly(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.redis = redis.Redis(config['redis_host'], config['redis_port'])

    def dispatch_request(self, request):
        return Response('Hello World!')

    def wsgi_app(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        response = self.dispatch_request(request)
        return response(environ, start_response)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)


def create_app(redis_host='localhost', redis_port=6379, with_static=True):
    app = Shortly({
        'redis_host':       redis_host,
        'redis_port':       redis_port
    })
    if with_static:
        app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
            '/static':  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
        })
    return app

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    app = create_app()
    run_simple('127.0.0.1', 5000, app, use_debugger=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation seems to be messed up in the last few lines. You need to move the `if __name__ == '__main__'`... block out of the `create_app` function.

```
# imports here...

# class and function definitions..

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    app = create_app()
    run_simple('127.0.0.1', 5000, app, use_debugger=True, use_reloader=True)
```